# In Modern Warfare 2, is it a realistic strategy to play free for all mode with a LMG?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Modern Warfare 2, is it a realistic strategy to play free for all mode with a LMG?

Is this a wise strategy? Should I go for a more "all round" fitout/perks when playing free for all? I seem to get a bunch of kills but get nailed on the smaller maps and anywhere with boxed killzones/corners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its 'realistic' to play with any gun.  An LMG is a very 'well rounded' gun.  If your having problems pulling it up in time use a slight of hand/ steady aim combination.  You can begin to shoot from the hip while pulling your gun up.

Most of this game is recognizing the strengths of your gun and sticking to areas that utilize it!  For example, if you use an RPD stick to open areas.  On the map 'Wasteland' stay outside of the bunker and try to engage your enemies at mid -> long range.  With the staggering power of secondary guns in this game, any primary gun is absolutely reasonable.  Stick with a pp2000, g18, or shotgun to balance out the mid -> long range requirements of your LMG  (a close -> mid range secondary to use when your LMG is too clunky)

The RPD with a grip is my favorite gun in the game: my k/d is 5.  If your looking for a higher kill/death use the ACR, UMP, or Scar.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

One of the big advantages of an LMG in FFA is that it can have a huge clip size.  In TDM, you usually have your allies at your back so ducking down to reload is not as big of a deal, whereas in FFA you have enemies coming from all sides!

One thing that might make a LMG easier to use is a fast secondary, like a pistol, Raffica or Throwing Knife.  Shotguns generally take a long time to pull out and since gun-switching with LMG's also takes a while, you only really want to switch in an emergency.  At least, that's what I've found.

Also, make sure you use a grip (unless you're in hard core, where you only need to hit one bullet.

RPD is also a great counter to shields, since it works well to spray momentarily exposed appendages.

Comment: No bullet from any gun can penetrate a shield, FMJ or not

Comment: I watched kill cam carefully this time, and I really can't tell.  RPD seems to be going through but it could just be a fast spray hitting spare limbs.  Either, I'm pretty good with the shield and the only two guns I can't run down reliably are AA and RPD :-p

Comment: http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Riot_Shield  RPD is great for spraying any limb sticking out of a shield, but no bullet penetrates a riot shield